# What Java embedded VM do you suggest for ARM development?

Tags: java, embedded, arm

There are a lot of Java embedded VMs. What do you suggest for ARM development?

- http://www.cacaovm.org/
- http://www.rtjcom.com/main.php?p=home
- http://www.k-embedded-java.com/
- http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/

I'm currently using the [TINI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Internet_Interface) platform from Dallas and works great (512 KB RAM and 1 MB flash), but now I need more power (memory and CPU).

Comment: There is also Oracle's Java 6 for ARM: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My final choice is JamVM + GNU Classpath. Works great! :)

Answer (score 4):

4 different VMs have been ported to Symbian OS, which runs on ARM cpus.

Sun's KVM, Sun's hotspot (or cldc-hi) VM, Sun's CDC VM and IBM J9 VM.

I suspect there are several more.

a good place to start your research would be the list of JavaME licensees:

http://java.sun.com/javame/licensees/index.jsp

Answer (score 2):

I have done some work the Dallas tini in the past so I think I know what you are looking for...? (maybe anyway :)

If you look at projects like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/), you will find that [jamvm](http://www.google.se/search?q=buildroot+jamvm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a) is now included, I plan to try it out on a [Atmel NGW100](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=4102) (it is based on a AVR32 but it is similar to a ARM9).
But there is a lot of other ARM9 projects that does nearly the same.

This idea is the same as with Android, first you let Linux take care of the lower layers and then you add a java vm on top and there you run your applications.

On the downside is that the Dallas tini was a more or less "ready" platform, you did not have do much magic to get it running. But this path will unfortunate require some work to get up to full speed. But on the good side you have a promise of a 200MHz 32bit CPU with 32Mb RAM and storage on a SD card that can easily store a couple of Giga Bytes :)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Java SE Embedded](http://java.sun.com/javase/embedded/) which supports ARMv5,v6,v7, be aware though that this is a full-blown Hotspot with C1 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You may also look at debian openjdk support, like

http://debian.torredehanoi.org/debian/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b11-9.1_armel.deb

But I think it requires more RAM than 512kB

Answer (score 0):

My choice goes to IS2T JVM, which is specially optimized for ARM Cortex M and Cortex A, with optimized libraries as well (like HMI with widgets etc...)

http://www.is2t.com