# Recommendation for Java VM running on embedded system

Tags: java-me, embedded, jvm, cdc

We are trying to support Java enviroment on our embedded platform (700 MHz [MIPS 74K](http://mipstechnologies.com/products/processors/32-64-bit-cores/mips32-74k/), 128-256 MB memory). After reading this [article](http://java-virtual-machine.net/other.html) and googling a bit, I came up with the shorted list:

- [Java ME from Sun](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/index.jsp)
- Kaffe
- [Jbed](http://www.esmertec.ch/)
- [Perc](http://www.aonix.com/perc.html)
- HP Chai VM
- [PhoneME](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/)　- seems the most promising one
- IBM [WEME](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/wireless/weme/) (Thanks to Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen)
- [Aplix JBlend](http://www.aplixcorp.com/) (Thanks to QuickRecipesOnSymbian)

I was quite new to Java and its runtime enviroment. What do you recommend for a Java VM running on MIPS 74K?

Comment: IBM also has an embedded JVM - http://www-01.ibm.com/software/wireless/weme/ - available for MIPS.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Aplix JBlend](http://www.aplixcorp.com) and at a similar Stack Overflow question, "[What Java embedded VM do you suggest for ARM development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638087/what-java-embedded-vm-do-you-suggest-for-arm-development)".