# MIDLet managers for Android/Windows devices

Tags: android, windows-mobile, emulation, midlet

I seem to be a bit at loss with the status and development of MIDlet managers for Android or Windows Mobile devices.

I know of JBlend and JBed but I can't work out who those projects belong to.
JBlend is installed on my LG540 by the manufacturer but not on Galaxy S1 for example.
I need to find a way to give a reliable set of instructions to the users to get these installed on their device.

- Is there is a central place to download them from?
- Is there a road map for those projects (i.e Android 2.3)?
- Why aren't those available from the Market place?
- Is a midlet manager available on all Windows mobile 7 devices?

Comment: See also JBlend - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735270/recommendation-for-java-vm-running-on-embedded-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some (eg. JBed) were said to be found on Android Market, however those were probably from some 3rd parties without legal rights, they don't appear on the Market now.

**JBed :**

I found some versions of JBed were ripped off of firmwares of some Android phones. The company doesn't have it listed as a downloadable product, so it seems to be developed for bigger companies, like phone manufacturers, to be integrated in their firmwares. That seems to be the reason why we don't see much info or new releases.

JBed is owned by Myriad Group (formerly known as Esmertec)
http://www.myriadgroup.com

**Netmite App Runner :**

App Runner is a converter + Android runtime (for shared java functions). It's said to be a corporation, though it looks like a one-man operation. The 'homepage' of the website instantly redirects to the 'Android App Runner' pages, which are just a few poorly structured html text, with poorly written English, and the author uses the words 'we' and 'I' interchangeably. No company info. The application is not available on stock market applications, to what I see.

http://www.netmite.com/android/

Most (all?) Java emulators need root access, and require phone owners to do some hacks on the device, which in most situations invalidate their warranties. This is another disadvantage for them to spread.

I would expect a stock java emulator on most phone models, probably license fees and maintenance (firmware updates) are keeping manufacturers away.